# Create a list from a list of objects

Tags: java, list

Consider I have a VO Employee with following fields.

**Employee**

```
EmployeeId
EmployeeName
EmployeeDOB
EmployeeAddress
```

I have a list of Employee VOs, say EmployeeList.
I want to create another list of all the EmployeeIds in the EmployeeList.
I know the most common way is to iterate EmployeeList and add one by one to EmployeeIdList, but is there any way to do it in single shot ?
Here is the current code.

```
List<Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList<Employee>();
populate(employeeList); //this will add EmployeeVOs to the list
List<String> employeeIdList = new ArrayList<String>();
for(Employee emp:employeeList)
{
 employeeIdList.add(emp.getEmployeeId()) ;
}
```

I want to know if there is a way to add all the employeeIds without the iteration of employeeList like above.
I don't want to change the existing populate method since its happening in EJB and is used by many other classes as well.

Comment: If you add each `employeeId` to a separate `List` in the `populate()` method itself , then you don't need to iterate through the `List` encore.

Comment: Java 8 (Lambda) has just provisions for such trivial tasks. A list adapter (Guava) implementing List<Integer> backed with the original list would save nothing, and not allow independent inserts/removes.

Comment: I don't want to change the existing populate method since its happening in EJB and is used by many other classes as well.

Answer (score 4):

Try [LambdaJ](https://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/):

```
List<String> employeeIds = extract(employeeList,on(Employee.class).getEmployeeId());
```

I've been using the project for a while and while it has a bit of a learning curve, I've really come to appreciate it.

Note that those method calls (`extract` and `on`) are static methods in the `Lambda` class so you'd do a static import on that class so the code looks pretty.

Comment: I was hoping for something which will come with Java 6. Wouldn't be worth adding new Jars for such a small comfort.:) Will sure try this for academic purpose.

Comment: There's no one-liner in Java6 without bringing in an additional library or rolling your own.  I brought it into one of my projects more for academic purposes as well but once I played with it a bit, I find most of my collection manipulation code has started using Lambdaj.  It will tie me over until Java 8.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) with the ID as key, this way you will have one collection and you can add both in `populate(employeeList)` in one iteration. What you want (adding id one-liner) sounds like a job for [lambdas](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) in java8.

Comment: I don't want to change the existing populate method since its happening in EJB and is used by many other classes as well. Looks like I'll have to proceed with the current code. Was hoping to find something more neat.

Comment: Also the Map wouldn't work if I need a list of employeeNames next time. So was hoping for something like an API.

Comment: Then I recommend building your own collection, I am not aware of any libs that provide all of what you seek.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there is a way to **transform** the original `List<Employee>` into a `List<String>` one without iterating it. My approach is usually using the [Guava Collections](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) framework:

```
List<Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList<Employee>();
populate(employeeList);
List<String> employeeIdList = Lists.transform(employeeList, new Function<Employee, String>() {
     public String apply(Employee input) {
         Preconditions.checkNotNull(input);
         return input.getEmployeeId();
     }
});
```

Guava doesn't iterate through the original list at that point yet, it wraps it into another different list and performs the transformation **on the fly** when the elements are accessed. Problem is: you can't perform additions/insertions in the result list and, at some point, you'll need to iterate through it.

Answer (score 0):

No matter if there is any other way or not, but eventually it will be done via iteration only.

Further, I don't think there is any direct API that can help you in achieving that.

So, whatever you are doing is the best way of doing this.

And one more thing, you can do it while populating Employee VOs. At that time you can either create a Map or a separate List for employee ids.

But again, it will be just an optimization.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there isn't.

2 things however. You could populate the id list at the same time you populate the VO one, this will avoid you an additional iteration on the VO List.

If you remain on the way presented here, i would advise to provide the list size at initialization of the id list, to avoid multiple reallocation of the underlying array in the ArrayList.

```
List<String> employeeIdList = new ArrayList<String>(employeeIdList.size());
```

To optimize Collection manipulation you should consider operations done on this collection to choose the more appropriate implementation. (add / remove operation mainly => LinkedList, random access (get(n)) => arrayList, contains => Set, etc...)